# Buying userpoints?

Tags: commerce, userpoints

I am using Drupal Commerce, Userpoints, and Commerce Userpoints. How can I add the possibility for a user to buy some userpoints with different payment methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a product of type **userpoints** and upon successful payment add a **rule** to update userpoints for that user.